# Google Sheets AND and OR Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm still new to Google Sheets and still learning, so in my GS I tried using `AND` and `OR` formula to produce the results like: -

```
A | B 
-----
1 | 1  TRUE
1 | 2  TRUE
2 | 1  TRUE
2 | 2  FALSE
3 | 1  FALSE
3 | 2  FALSE
```

But this is the closest I [get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pri6C.png). What is the best formula that will help me produce result like I shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule is not entirely clear. For instance, could there be zero values? Negative values? But since you have not included such examples in your sample set, the following formula will produce the desired result according to the only data you've included.

Assuming you have headers in A1 and B1 and that your numeric data runs A2:B, delete everything from Col C (including any header) and place the following formula in C1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header";IF(A2:A="",,A2:A+B2:B<=3)})`

This one formula will produce all results for all rows (again, judging by the very small data set and implied rule for such in our post).

You can change `Header` to any header text you like.

The rest reads this way: "If any cell in A2:A is empty, return null in the corresponding cell of that row in Col C. Otherwise, assess whether the combined total of the numbers in Col A and Col B is less than or equal to 3 and return TRUE or FALSE accordingly."